# Instance object with ambigous constructor parameters; yet C# instances it

Tags: c#

I have a class called `AlertDialogViewModel` with two constructors, one taking an `Object` and a `string` and another taking two `string`s.

```
public class AlertDialogViewModel
{
    public AlertDialogViewModel(object contentObject, string title)
    {
        this.ContentObject = contentObject;
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public AlertDialogViewModel(string contentString, string title)
    {
        this.ContentString = contentString;
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public object ContentObject { get; set; }

    public string ContentString { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In a unit test, I create a new instance with the first parameter being null.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Instancing_string_alert_with_null_content_throws_exception()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string title = "Unit Test";

        // Act
        var alertDialog = new AlertDialogViewModel(null, title);
    }
```

When I run the unit test, it uses the constructor that takes a string as a first parameter. What is the compiler/runtime doing to determine that is the correct constructor that needs to be used?

This isn't causing any issues with my code, I am just wanting to understand why that constructor is selected in the event that in the future this actually does matter.

Comment: In C#, `string` is a reference type, not a value type. Therefore, a `string` can be null

Comment: It's because `string` is considered more specific than `object`.

Comment: Note also than you can explicitly cast `null` using `(T)null` or `null as T` to resolve issues like these explicitly

Comment: So the 2nd constructor is invoked only because it's more specific? What if I have the constructors first type `Person` and `Car`. How does it infer which constructor to pass null to?

Comment: juharr is right. If one overload takes `Person`, and another takes `Car`, and both these types are reference types, and neither is more specific than the other, and these are the only two (relevant) overloads, then a binding-time error occurs if the argument is a "naked" `null`.